# Testing user base by performing scheduled dictionary attacks

Tags: php, security, brute-force

For my new website, written in PHP, I intent to regularly test the vulnerability of my users' passwords. My main concern is whether a brute force attack can be used (e.g. a dictionary attack).

My current design is to use a security script that performs a dictionary attack on a number of users. After the script has established that the password can be hacked, I want to send a mail to the user that we strongly advice them to improve the password. The mailing, scripting etc part is easy. However, can someone give me pointers how to implement this dictionary "attack"?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

EDIT: The bit I'm actually interested in, is when the "hacker" tries to get entry to the website via the normal login form.

My current countermeasures already are: In the current db all passwords are encrypted with BCrypt, I use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection, a temporary lock-out (5 minutes) when one IP adres has tried too many times, and try to prevent XSS.

However, I still want to warn a user when I deem his password not safe, without just shutting him out, the choice is still up to him if he wants to continue with this password.

Comment: You'd rather protect your system from this kind of attacks (as much as you can). The first thing that I think of would be to limit the number of tries and increase the time the user has to wait between tries and/or use a captcha (or simply block any attempt) when a particular threshold is reached. I'm sure you'll find a lot more information here if you browse some of the related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is vital that you first protect your site from brute force attacks(lockout) a dictionary test is actually quite good and can assist users by informing them they are using weak passwords.

Another argument that can occur is to not allow user signups with weak passwords. If you choose this method then I am of the ilk that you are doing yourself and the internet as a whole a favor. The standard user would argue against this though and there is the potential loss of users/customers.

Depressingly most will ignore it, but some will listen. Anyhoo. Down to code :)

So firstly build your password list, it does not take a genius to google for one. We will pretend that list.txt is your password list.

Edited: Implemented various rules to generate passwords from passed string so that even if we only have a relatively weak password list we can return multiple versions of it.

```
$users = array(); // Fill it via any means you want, we will 
                  // pretend its an array of username + password

foreach($users as $user) {
    // We are going to loop through each line in the list and 
    // then check it against the password
    while($line = fread('list.txt')) {
        $hashes = $this->hashPassword($line);
        foreach($hashes as $hash) {
            if($user['password'] == $hashedPassword) { 
                echo $user['username'] . ' has a weak password of ' . $line . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}

function hashPassword($password) {
    $simple = hash('sha256', $password);
    $numberReplace = hash('sha256', str_replace(array("o", "i", a"), array(0, 1, 4), $password)); 
    $stupidUserPassword = hash('sha256', ucfirst($password) . "1");

    return array($simple, $numberReplace, $stupidUserPassword);
}
```

This is but one example so look at some other answers too which might be helpful. Any questions feel free to ask.

Edit 1: Awesome commentor spotted a flaw in my logic, tbh it was a fairly horrible flaw - cheers.

Edit 2: Google rainbow tables and how to generate for your particular needs. Pre-hashed lists that would speed up this execution if you are really hardcore about it :)

Comment: I suppose something thats not strictly SOish, but being polite and not repeatedly informing them of weak passwords would also be advised.

Comment: This approach wouldn't work if the passwords are salted correctly. Salting is intended to prevent such a sweeping attack. You'd need to iterate through each user, then each dictionary entry.

Comment: @PaulG Cheers for spotting. Tbh I am suprised that I did not notice that.

Comment: @NeilMasters, thank you for this approach. The main problem with dictionary attacks is that they also tend to add a year, use 1337 etc. Wouldn't such a script have an enormous (time) complexity if you would have to replace all text via a 1337 scheme and try all possible years? Do you reckon you have to do that?

Comment: You should definitely test everything and anything. There is no point going all half measures :) You could modify the hashPassword function to return an array of hashes for you to test which performs all your permutations and then goes through that returned array. Edited answer as a demo.

Answer (score 0):

In it's most simple form you could compare the plain text password (which you have only at the time of user registration) against every line in a dictionary. I think that approach is simple enough that a code example is not needed.

However the fact that you're concerned about this suggests that you may be implementing your hashes incorrectly.

You should be generating a unique salt for each hash, and using that as a prefix to the password. This salt adds strength to passwords which would otherwise be weak, and therefore means a dictionary search is pointless.

The consequence of adding salt means any attacker can only attack a single password at a time, (and needs to know the unique salt). It basically defeats a brute force attack where the attacker does not know the salt. And radically slows down an attack where the attacker *does* know the salt

Comment: I do use a combination of a unique salt, password and username, which in itself would make the hash "impossible" to crack, so the db is safe. Furthermore, the backend will dump the connection after a number of tries. But, lets say, a botnet is used to attack the regular login, in which they know the e-mail. For these cases, I want to make sure the passwords in itself cannot be guesed, for example with a dictionary attack.